# Degree of minimal polynomial for $\sin(\pi/m)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

What is the general formula for the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sin(\pi/m)$? There are plenty of questions on this site asking for particular $m$, and I know that this has some connection to the Chebyshev polynomials, but I can't seem to find any good source with a straight answer.

If this question doesn't have any known simple answers, then are there any inequalities, perhaps of the type $\deg(m)\geq \varphi(m)/2$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287109/minimal-polynomial-of-cos%CF%80-n See this question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319458/how-to-find-the-degree-of-sin2-pi-n-over-mathbbq and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352274/a-question-about-the-degree-of-sin2%cf%80-n-over-the-rationals and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529687/degree-of-the-field-extension-generated-by-sin2-pi-n-for-any-natural-number